# How are parameters updated with SGD-Optimizer?

Tags: neural-network, sgd

So I have found a formula describing the SGD-Descent

`θ = θ-η*∇L(θ;x,y)`

Where θ is a parameter, η is the learning rate and ∇L() is the gradient descent of the loss-function. But what I don't get is how the parameter θ (which should be weight and bias) can be updated mathematically? Is there a mathematical interpretation of the parameter θ?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

That formula applies to both gradient descent and stochastic gradient descent (SGD). The difference between the two is that in SGD the loss is computed over a random subset of the training data (i.e. a mini-batch/batch) as opposed to computing the loss over all the training data as in traditional gradient descent. So in SGD `x` and `y` correspond to a subset of the training data and labels, whereas in gradient descent they correspond to all the training data and labels.

`θ` represents the parameters of the model. Mathematically this is usually modeled as a vector containing all the parameters of the model (all the weights, biases, etc...) arranged into a single vector. When you compute the gradient of the loss (a scalar) w.r.t. `θ` you get a vector containing the partial derivative of loss w.r.t. each element of `θ`. So `∇L(θ;x,y)` is just a vector, the same size as `θ`. If we were to assume that the loss were a linear function of `θ`, then this gradient points in the direction in parameter space that would result in the maximal *increase* in loss with a magnitude that corresponds to the expected increase in loss if we took a step of size 1 in that direction. Since loss isn't actually a linear function and we actually want to decrease loss we instead take a smaller step in the opposite direction, hence the η and minus.

It's also worth pointing out that mathematically the form you've given is a bit problematic. We wouldn't usually write it like this since assignment and equal aren't the same thing. The equation you provided would seem to imply that the `θ` on the left-hand and right-hand side of the equation were the same. They are not. The `θ` on the left side of the equal sign represents the value of the parameters after taking a step and the `θ`s on the right side correspond to the parameters before taking a step. We could be more clear by writing it with subscripts

[image]

where `θ_{t}` is the parameter vector at step `t` and `θ_{t+1}` is the parameter vector one step later.

Comment: Good answer. Perhaps worth mentioning too that SGD is just one of many iterative methods for optimization of a linear system under some convex loss. The "difference" between them is typically some combination of choice of learning rate and the gradient direction at each step.